# Using IEEEeqnarray environment in multiline equation

Tags: equations

I am trying to get my equation

```
$\begin{equation}\label{form explicitely}
F_{\mathfrak{B}}(x,y)=\frac{((t^3-2t^2p+t(q+p^2)+r-pq)}{f^2}x^3+
\frac{((-3t^2+4tp-   (p^2+q))}{f}x^2y+(3t-2p)xy^2-fy^3
\end{equation}$
```

which looks like this

[image]

to look more or less like this one

[image]

which has the following code

```
$\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{l} a+b+c+d+e+f \\ \qquad +\> g + h + i + j + k + l \qquad \\
\IEEEeqnarraymulticol{1}{r}{
+\>m+n+o+p+q } \IEEEyesnumber
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}$
```

[image]

but it just does not look as nice: I am unable to shift every line in the way it is done in the eq (32)

Any help appreciated

Comment: Did you try just using a regular align* environment, and just adding more align points on the + signs?

Comment: You haven't really got `$` signs around your equation environment have you? That would generate multiple errors. Please always post complete documents not just fragments, and show the output _from the posted document_.

Comment: Sorry. Next time when I post a problem I will do as you say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\begin{document}

\begin{multline}\label{form explicitely}
F_{\mathfrak{B}}(x,y)=\frac{((t^3-2t^2p+t(q+p^2)+r-pq)}{f^2}x^3\\
{}+\frac{((-3t^2+4tp-   (p^2+q))}{f}x^2y\\
{}+(3t-2p)xy^2-fy^3
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you David it does look much nicer. I wonder if it is possible to move the last term a bit more to the left?

Comment: @user124471 You can always put \hspace{1cm} at the end of the last line